# Call Intent(this, SomeClass.class) in Frida

Tags: android, frida

How would I go about calling the equivalent of this in Frida?

`Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, SomeClass.class);`

Which was called from a Java function.

I have tried doing something such as:

```
var intent = Java.use('android.content.Intent');
var randClass = Java.use("RandClass");
var someClass = Java.use("SomeClass");

randClass.func.implementation = function() {
   var result = intent(randClass, someClass);
}
```

Which did not work.

Answer (score 3):

Use `$new` to create new instance and `.class` or cast to `java.lang.Class`

```
randClass.func.implementation = function() {
   var result = intent.$new(/*currentActivity*/, someClass.class);
}
```

You need save the current activity, hooking `onCreate` might do the job.